# where WSO2 governance registry store added wsdl files stored in local system

Tags: wsdl, wso2

where WSO2 governance registry store added wsdl files stored in local system.What does mean that /_system/governance/trunk/wsdl, where does it located in local system. 
Can any one help to solve.

Answer (score 0):

It will be stored in Database. (registry database)

Comment: But I haven't found any resource stored in Database, can you please tell me where in database table.